# C# Alpha Blended form with Alpha Blended Controls

Tags: c#, forms, controls, alpha, blend

Alpha blended forms are no problem (for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/alphaBG.aspx) but alpha blended controls like pictureboxes with 32bit images don't work...

Here is my problem:

I have the alpha blended form (which doesn't have to be alpha blended)  and on a full transparent part of the form I want to draw the picturebox with an 32bit image. But this Image has at the background the transparent color(Fuchsia)

How can I make it, that the picturebox is also fully blended?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread on the MSDN forum
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/9aeab184-2a45-4bd4-8157-2a629523e80b/ and this one on C# Corner http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB10102005010514AM/DrawTransparentImageUsingAB.aspx

Comment: Hmm, thats not exactly what Im looking for:
I want to have a alpha blended pictureBox (therefore a 32bit image) on a transparent zone of the form (so without the backcolor)
Is that possible?